How to make Shift+A work in Blender 4.0
Shift+A doesn't work in Blender 4.0 outside of the 3D workspace to bring up the Add menu. So it's not working in the Geometry Node workspace, Shader menu, compositor etc.
What is the best way to troubleshoot how to activate this again?

It should work, maybe check your preferences?

I can't find where I should be looking in preferences. Any thoughts?

Preferences > Keymap > Name > type "Add" then check under Node Editor what's the shortcut for the simple Add

Thanks, that did the job.

Preferences > Keymap > Name > type "Add" then check under Node Editor what's the shortcut for the simple Add.

Preferences > Keymap > Name > type "Add" then check under Node Editor
Shift+A is the default so if it's not working you will see an option to 'Restore'. Click that button and it will restore a particular window/mode's shortcuts to their default, including A = Shift+A

Answer courtesy of moonboots


If the answer helps you, make sure to let the user post the answer and then mark that one as the correct one
